# Apache PDFBox Image text

Tags: java, pdfbox

Can anyone give a hint on how to add a "alt text" to an image in a pdf-document created by PDFBox.

I would like the text to appear when hovering over the image.

I have already added the image to the document and all is looking good. Just missing the "alt text"

Comment: do you have a PDF where that happens? Maybe a square annotation with an invisible border. See the AddAnnotations.java example. However I noticed that the text appears only when the mouse is at the edge or at the speech bubble.

Comment: Great, I'll have a look. This is really about making the file accessible so a screenreader has to be able to pick up the text annotated to the image.

Comment: Also please mention which PDF viewer you use. There is very little in the PDF specification on such visual extras, so don't count on tool tips available on arbitrary viewers. If you want accessibility, you should focus on tagging, not on tool tips.

Comment: I'm using Acrobat Reader. Ok, good point. Maybe I try another reader or a screenreader like JAWS.
I can have a look if there is a good example on tagging on the PDFBox website

Comment: I belive I did use tagging in this code: